# Can someone assist me with removing openvpn from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: uninstall, vpn, openvpn

So i was trying to install [PrivateInternetAccess](https://privateinternetaccess.com) on my computer and I found some instructions on their website, they had a download for a file but I couldn't figure out how to open the `.sh` file.

So i went to google and found these instructions. It said to perform the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install curl network-manager-openvpn-gnome
wget https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/pia-nm.sh
sudo bash pia-nm.sh
```

After doing these it installed the VPN but not how I wanted or thought it would. I wanted the application installed and this just put all the VPN connections in my network settings under VPN.

Anyway I figured out how to install the application like I wanted, and now I'm trying to undo where I installed OpenVPN and the other commands. I want to remove the VPN connections from my network settings.

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove curl network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

This seemed to remove the software. But it is still installed apparently. 
I did this to check if it was removed:

```
dpkg --list openvpn

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-=============================================

pi  openvpn              2.4.4-2ubuntu1. amd64           virtual private network daemon
```

(also, the pi next to open VPN was `ii` earlier, now its showing as pi. Dont know if thats important)

but it shows up anyway. So i noticed when i first installed Ubuntu that it had a VPN section in my network settings from the beginning. Is OpenVPN just part of the system? I tried to remove it again with

```
sudo dpkg -r openvpn
sudo dpkg --purge openvpn
```

Both of these failed saying there were dependency problems. I mean its not the end of the world if I cant remove it, but I'd like to know how to. 
Also can someone help me with understanding how to remove the VPN connections?

I dont know how to undo what I did and google isnt helping me very much with this. I know I could go through each connection inside my network settings and click the gear and then click remove, but i want to know how to undo it from terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why you used `dpkg` to remove OpenVPN, in that case try again but with `apt` this time.

First, fix any dependencies problem that you might occur, by adding `--fix` parameter on apt.

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Finally, remove `openvpn` with all their dependencies.

```
sudo apt purge openvpn
```

Please report back any error, if any.

Comment: Okay cool, this worked and now when i do: dpkg --list openvpn it doesnt show up. I used dpkg because i saw it in youtube videos. Should i just use apt instead? im just trying to learn the best way to do things.

Comment: I keep trying to mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark but it won't let me.  And i tried to vote up on the other answer because it was also helpful but it wont let me do that either. I will try again later.

Comment: @Rusynic why do you un-accept the answer ?

Comment: I dont know what im doing. I am trying to select it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked except for :
dpkg: warning: while removing openvpn, directory '/var/log/openvpn' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing openvpn, directory '/etc/openvpn/client' not empty so not removed
 I then manually removed those

Comment: This didn't work for me, it still shows up and the service is still running.
`$ dpkg --list openvpn'
'Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  openvpn        <none>       <none>       (no description available)`

Answer (score 1):

• To delete your OpenVPN profiles via shell,

`ll /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

You'll see all your saved connections. Use command `sudo rm -vf connection_name` to delete the OpenVPN profiles you want, you can use regular expressions like `sudo rm -vf US*` to remove all the profiles that start with "US".

• `pi` from `dpkg --list openvpn` says the state of the `openvpn` package, `p` = the desired state (marked for action) of openvpn which is `purged` (that you did), `i` = the current state of the package which is `installed` (meaning it's not removed yet). `ii` meant `i` = desired state `installed`, `i` = current state `installed`.

• Depending on how you installed `openvpn` there are many possibilities, it's possible that PIA is interfering with the package or PIA is a opnvpn client and depends on it. Try to fix broken packages with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, completely remove PIA, then remove `openvpn`. Anyway if it doesn't work, try this command `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all openvpn`. If all fails, then you might have to search & manually delete all binary files of `openvpn`.

• You might also want to consider reinstalling `curl`, it comes pre-instaled with Ubuntu and an important download utility, `sudo apt install curl`

Comment: This worked also, the terminal displayed each connection being removed. I used sudo rm -vf PIA*   because each connection was marked with PIA at the front. After that i restarted the network manager with  sudo service network-manager restart   and then all the connections were gone from the VPN menu. Much appreciated. Also thanks for explaining what pi, ii and all that means. Now i know what im looking at.